# Java ArrayList .add() overwrites previous values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

**I've already checked out other people who were facing the same issue**, & almost all of them were instantiating the objects they want to add outside their loop. I'm already doing that inside my while loop, so I'm guessing that's not my issue.

```
public ArrayList<SHMapTile> tiles = new ArrayList<SHMapTile>();
.
.
.
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    int i = 0;

    while ( eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT )
    {
        String name = null;

        switch ( eventType )
        {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            {
                name = parser.getName();

                if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase("tile") )
                {
                    SHMapTile tile = new SHMapTile();
                    tile.gid = i;

                    tiles.add(tile);
                    System.out.println("gid: " + tiles.get(0).gid);
                    i++;
                }

                break;
            }

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            {
                name = parser.getName();

                if ( name.equalsIgnoreCase("data") )
                {
                    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            drawCurrentMapRegion();
                        }
                    });
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        eventType = parser.next();
    }
}
```

For debugging, I attached a counter to each new object. When I print out the counter of the first element in the list, it's always different. I tried cloning. Didn't work either.

Comment: ArrayList allows duplicate values. Provide your full code. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: Among other things, you don't show how you're sharing that list with the UI thread, and whether you have proper synchronization.

Comment: @MachOSX is that your issue? `ArrayList` not guaranteed insertion order. When you add a new element order of element may changed. If you want to keep insertion order use `LinkedList`

Comment: My guess: field `gid` of class `SHMapTile` is `static`. Is it? Can you share the code for that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in comments, field `gid` of class `SHMapTile` is `static`.

That means that the same value is shared between *all* instances of the class. If you update one, it will be updated in all istances of that class. Remove the `static` modifier and it will work